# Exclusive CSS for iPhone/Android

Tags: iphone, android, html, css, mobile

I'm making a mobile-friendly stylesheet for a page of mine. Is there a simple way to make it show that stylesheet to iPhone/Android users? Or do I have to pull the user-agents and figure it out that way - and how do I do that?

Also - any tools to make this sort of web dev easier?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do something like this, if your stylesheet is the same for iOS/android.

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />`

But if you're trying to detect if it's the iOS OR Android, then you'll need to do detection.

In terms of making mobile dev easier, there's a ton of stuff:

- http://www.phonegap.com/
- http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/
- http://www.appcelerator.com/
- [http://www.jquerymobile.com/](http://jquerymobile.com/)
- http://www.jqtouch.com/

There's a few to get you started :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: you forgot dojo ! I've done a lot with that and I thinks its far better than any of these

Answer (score 7):

Try this, using navigator.userAgent in JavaScript ;) (courtesy of this awesome post http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/):

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/))) {
   alert("we've got an iDevice, Scotty");
}

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/)) {
   alert("Droid me baby");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

detect what exactly use user, and style for his mobile device

iphone 4

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    .inphone4CSS{}
}
```

traget Target Samsung Galaxy S2

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 534px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    .GalaxyS2_CSS{}
}
```

more about it(or another devices) you can find here:
[Target a specific device](http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/)

Comment: This won't work in Android world where there are a countless number of devices :-)

Comment: @RyanS answer published 5 years ago