# HTML5 optimized for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

I have a software that eventually will have some reports to be accessed via iPhone. 
Once I am not willing to develop an iPhone app, I´d like to make these reports accessible via iPhone Safari browsers.

GMail in iPad uses HTML 5, so I guess I can do the same.

My question is where can I find some resources to learn best practices doing so and how can I test it in a PC computer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar answer I've given:  [Exclusive CSS for iPhone/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050070/exclusive-css-for-iphone-android/5050111#5050111)

For testing you can use Chrome or Safari, as they are both webkit browsers (which is what the iPhone uses).  Safari can even render as the iPhone user agent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), I think that is what you are looking for.

You can emulate the program in xCode, but you will need an Apple for that. For PhoneGap also..

Answer (score 0):

From the app architecture view-point you should also consider introducing app-specific optimization such us:

- Simplify the app (show only what you need for mobile)
- Minimize Application and Data Size
- Aggregate Images into a Single Composite Resource (Sprites)
- Include Background Images Inline in CSS Style Sheets
- Keep DOM Size Reasonable
- Ensure Paragraph Text Flows
- Avoid Redirects